# Creating an observer to check if MediaPlayer playbackState is paused or not

Tags: swift

I have a music app and I wish to determine if playback has been paused while the app was closed (due to an event like a phone call or AirPods being taken out of ear etc)

My first approach was to run a func inside of `viewWillAppear` that checked

```
if mediaPlayer.playbackState == .paused {
    ...
}
```

If it was paused I updated the play/pause button image. However, this did not work, the play/pause button would still show Play even if it was paused.

Next, I tried adding an observer to the `viewDidLoad`

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.wasSongInterupted(_:)), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: self.mediaPlayer)
```

The `self.wasSongInterupted` I call is

```
@objc func wasSongInterupted(_ notification: Notification) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if self.mediaPlayer.playbackState == .paused {
            print("paused")
            self.isPlaying = false
            self.playPauseSongButton.isSelected = self.isPlaying
        } else if self.mediaPlayer.playbackState == .playing {
            self.isPlaying = true
            self.playPauseSongButton.isSelected = self.isPlaying
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am still having the same issue.

What is the best way to determine if my music player is playing or paused when I reopen the app?

Edit 1: I Edited my code based on comments.

`wasSongInterrupted` was not being called, and through breakpoints and errors I discovered the code was mostly not needed. I changed my code to be

```
func wasSongInterrupted() {
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    if self.mediaPlayer.playbackState == .interrupted {
      var isPlaying: Bool { return self.mediaPlayer.playbackState == .playing }
    print("Playback state is \(self.mediaPlayer.playbackState.rawValue), self.isPlaying Bool is \(self.isPlaying)")
      self.playPauseSongButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "playIconLight"), for: .normal)
      //self.playPauseSongButton.isSelected = self.isPlaying
    }
  }
}
```

and inside my AppDelegate's `applicationDidBecomeActive` I have

```
let mediaPlayerVC = MediaPlayerViewController()
mediaPlayerVC.wasSongInterupted()
```

Now the code runs, however I have an issue.

If I run the following code:

```
if self.mediaPlayer.playbackState == .interrupted {
  print("interrupted \(self.isPlaying)")
}
```

and then make a call and come back to the app it will hit the breakpoint. It will print out interrupted as well as false which is the Bool value for `self.isPlaying`

However if I try to update the UI by

```
self.playPauseSongButton.isSelected = self.isPlaying
```

or by

```
self.playPauseSongButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "playIconLight.png"), for: .normal)
```

I get an error message `Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x104af9258)`

Comment: Have you verified that `wasSongInterupted()` (*sic*) is being called at the appropriate times?

Comment: `viewWillAppear` is not called if your add becomes active after it was suspended. Try to check the media player status at `applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication)` and send the event to related view.

Comment: And your `isPlaying` property looks like it'd be better as a read-only computed property, like `var isPlaying: Bool { return mediaPlayer.playbackState == .playing }`. That way, you'll do less work trying to keep its value in sync with the media player's state.

Comment: @NRitH Thank you, it was not being called at appropriate times, ive fixed that but have new issues

Comment: @YuryImashev I put the function call there, it now calls but I am getting a new error (see updated question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You trying to update you player UI from `viewWillAppear`. From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621510-viewwillappear):

> **viewWillAppear(_:)**
>
> This method is called before the view controller's view is about to be added to a view hierarchy and before any animations are configured for showing the view.

So if your app was `suspended` and the becomes `active` again, this method won't be called, because your `UIViewController` is already at `Navigations Stack`.

If you want to catch the moment when your app becomes `active` from `suspended` state, you need to use `AppDelegate`. From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622956-applicationdidbecomeactive):

> **applicationDidBecomeActive(_:)**
>
> This method is called to let your app know that it moved from the inactive to active state. This can occur because your app was launched by the user or the system.

So you need to use this method at your `AppDelegate` to handle app running and update your interface.

**UPDATE**

You saying the inside this `AppDelegate` method you're doing

```
let mediaPlayerVC = MediaPlayerViewController()
mediaPlayerVC.wasSongInterupted()
```

That's wrong because you're creating a new view controller. What you need to do, is to access you **existing** view controller from navigation stack and update it.

One of the possible solutions is to use `NotificationCenter` to send a notification. You view controller should be subscribed to this event of course.

At first, you need to create a notification name

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let appBecameActive = Notification.Name(rawValue: "appBecameActive")
}
```

Then in you `AppDelegate` add following code to post your notifications when app becomes active

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .appBecameActive, object: nil)
}
```

And finally in your view controller add to subscribe it on notifications

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(wakeUp),
                                           name: .appBecameActive,
                                           object: nil)
    ...
}

@objc func wakeUp() {
    // Update your UI from here
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: If you look at the Edit I made to my question I stated that I am running it from my AppDelegate

Comment: @RubberDucky4444 yeah, sorry, I've decided to put all the logic into the answer for more context. I update it on your editings.

Comment: So create the notification inside applicationDidBecomeActive(_:)?

Comment: @RubberDucky4444 Yep. I've added the code that shows how to do that. This should work for you.